# how to grep for packages on basis of uncompressed file-size?

Tags: debian, grep, package-management, zsh

In Debian when you look at a package, you get lot of info. Including the uncompressed file size of the package. Is there a way to grep through the file-listing so that packages appear either from biggest to lowest or lowest to biggest ?

This is how it appears via aptitude :-

```
[$] aptitude show leafpad | grep Uncompressed

Uncompressed Size: 739 k
```

I am sure there is a way to do the same, but how? I am on zsh.

I am looking for all available package listing and would like it in human-readable way (i.e. KB/MB/GB etc.)

Repping @Theophrastus for the effort though.

Comment: "grep"? well, if sorted is the key then how about this?: `dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Package;-50}\t${Installed-Size} ${Status}\n' | sort -k 2 -n |grep -v deinstall`

Comment: What packages do you want? All installed packages? All available packages? All manually installed packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want something like this:

```
# apt-get install dctrl-tools
$ sort-dctrl -k Installed-Size:n /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages | grep-dctrl -ns Package,Installed-Size -
```

You get numbers in units of kB = 1024 bytes. Converting the output would be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

## Using *aptitude* `--sort` parameter

Theoretically you should be able to use *aptitude*'s search and sort facilities directly – sadly there seems to be a bug that causes *aptitude* to output packages with state `c` (deleted packages with configuration files still on the system) last and in a rather unsorted order:

```
aptitude -F '%p %I' search '!~v' --sort "installsize"
```

Where `-F` is used to tell *aptitude* how to format the output: `%p` is the package name, `%I` the estimated install size.  Check out the section [Customizing how packages are displayed](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s04s01.html#secDisplayFormat) in the *aptitude* reference manual if you want to learn more about how to format *aptitude*'s output.

The search term `!~v` selects all non-virtual packages: `!` is used for negation, and `~v` selects virtual packages.  Have a look at the [Search Term Reference](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html) for more ways to search the package database using *aptitude*; for example: if you are only interested in installed packages you would use `~i`.

`--sort` does the obvious thing of telling *aptitude* to sort the listing by certain criteria (a comma separated list of criteria) and  `installsize` is the criterion for the Uncompressed/Installed size; you can invert the sort direction by prepending `~` to the criterion: `~installsize`.  There is a section in the *aptitude* manual for those, too: [Customizing how packages are sorted](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s04s01.html#secSortingPolicy).

## Piping a package listing to `sort`

```
aptitude --disable-columns -F '%p %I' search '!~v' | sed 's/ \([^ ]\{1,2\}\)$/\1/' | sort -k2 -h | column -t
```

`--disable-columns` is necessary as to not confuse the selection of the sort column with *sort*'s `-k` argument.

`sed` is required because the space between the size number and it's qualifier (i.e. the MB in "4,897 MB") cause *sort* to not pick up the qualifier for the `--human-numeric-sort` (`-h`).

After the sorting `column -t` will create a pretty, columnified display of the package listing.

Comment: Strange (using Aptitude version `0.6.3`): Running `aptitude -F '%p %I' search '~i' --sort "installsize"` results in a list that omits about half of my installed packages, while running `aptitude --disable-columns -F '%p %I' search '~i' | sed 's/ \([^ ]\{1,2\}\)$/\1/' | sort -k2 -h | column -t` lists _all_ of my installed packages(!)