# sort-dctrl - How to get the output one screenful at a time on stdout?

Tags: debian, grep, package-management

I had asked a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245140/how-to-grep-for-packages-on-basis-of-uncompressed-file-size) on dctrl-tools almost a year ago, the winning answer was -

```
$ sort-dctrl -k Installed-Size:n /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages | grep-dctrl -ns Package,Installed-Size -
```

The problem is, the moment I let the command run, the output goes screenfuls and I get nothing out of it. I could pipe it to another .txt file . Is there anyway to ask it to give the information one screenful at a time .

Trying to do -

```
[$] sort-dctrl -k Installed-Size:n /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages | grep-dctrl -ns Package,Installed-Size - | less
```

does give the name of the packages but doesn't give the size. I even tried 'more' but the result is same.

I dunno if it's a bug or it needs to be done in a different way ?

Comment: what about the good old `| less` behind your command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should be:

```
 sort-dctrl -k Installed-Size:n,Size:nr /var/lib/dpkg/available | grep 'Size\|Package'
```

or :

```
sort-dctrl -k Installed-Size:n /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages | grep 'Size\|Package'
```